# Sending ANSI-Colored codes text to 3 outputs: screen, file and file filtering ANSI codes

Tags: shell, colors, ansi-escape

My program is sending **characters-colored** text to some log file:

```
echo -e "\\033[38;5;2m-->\\033[0m Starting program." | tee $LogFile -a
```

Resulting in a perfectly colored log line, but I would like to simultaneously create **another logfile without ANSI** codes, due to I need to browse this log in Windows (I know there are some ANSI browsers for Windows, but I prefer to browse the log files using Total Commander, that has no decent plugin for that).

So, I need three outputs in my log line:

- Some colored `--> Starting program.` line **to screen**.
- The same colored `--> Starting program.` line to the **logfile with ANSI** codes.
- The same not colored `--> Starting program.` line to the **logfile** (supposedly **without ANSI** codes, or so I think).

The above line was fine thanks to the `tee` command, that solves points 1 and 2, but I don't know how to add some option to save to another file but without ANSI codes, at least without **replicating the full line**.
Maybe using redirectors, file descriptor, with the help of mkfifo?

My workaround for now is, by the way, *duplication of outputs* (what becomes a bit awkward):

```
echo -e "\\033[38;5;2m--> Starting program.\\033[0m" | tee $LogFile -a
echo "--> Starting program." >> $NotANSILogFile
```

Answer (score 3):

To send the ansi codes to a log file, `ansi.log`, and to the screen, while also sending a non-ansi version to a log file called `nonansi.log`, use:

```
echo -e "\\033[38;5;2m-->\\033[0m Starting program." | tee -a ansi.log | tee /dev/tty | sed $'s/\E[^m]*m//g' >>nonansi.log
```

#### How it works

- `tee -a ansi.log`

  The first `tee` command appends the ansi-encoded string the the log file `ansi.log`.
- `tee /dev/tty`

  The second `tee` command sends the ansi-encoded string to the screen.  (`/dev/tty` is the file name of the current screen.)
- `sed $'s/\E[^m]*m//g' >>nonansi.log`

  The final command, `sed` removes the ansi sequences and the result is appended to `nonansi.log`.

  The `sed` command is contained in a `bash` `$'...'` string so that the escape character can be represented simply as `\E`.  This substitute command looks for sequences that start with escape, `\E`, and end with `m` and removes them.  The final `g` tells `sed` to perform this substitution on every escape sequence on the line, not just the first one.

  If you have GNU `sed`, an alternative is to use GNU's `\o` notation instead:

  ```
  sed 's/\o033[^m]*m//g' >>nonansi.log
  ```

  If you have neither GNU `sed` nor `bash`, then you need to see what facilities your `sed` or your shell provide for the Esc character.

#### Hiding the details in a shell function

If you need to make multiple log entries, it might be easiest to create a shell function, `logger`, to hold all the messy details:

```
logger() { echo -e "$*" | tee -a ansi.log | tee /dev/tty | sed $'s/\E[^m]*m//g' >>nonansi.log; }
```

With this function defined, then any log entry can be performed by providing the ansi-encoded string as an argument:

```
logger "\\033[38;5;2m-->\\033[0m Start."
```

Comment: More elegant than my method, thanks you. In the function definition I have used `"$1"` instead of your `"$*"`. Is it supposed to be better or worst?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez It is just a convenience: it allows the string to be spread over several arguments. For example, with `$*`, the following works `logger this is my message`.  With `$1`, it would have to be written `logger "this is my message"`.

Answer (score 2):

This method works (needs `perl` installed) to send output to **screen** (ANSI) and **two files**: `$LogFile` (ANSI) and `$LogFile.plain` (ANSI-free):

```
echo -e "\\033[38;5;2m--> Starting program.\\033[0m" | tee >(perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g'>>"$LogFile".plain) $LogFile -a
```

Details:

- The `tee` command splits output to both screen(stdout) and to the `perl` command.
- The `perl` line filters the ANSI codes.
- The output of `perl` is redirected to the plain Non-ANSI log file (used `LogFile.plain` for its filename).

To send **output only to files** (not to screen) do (same with just a classic `>/dev/null`).

```
echo -e "\\033[38;5;2m--> Starting program.\\033[0m" | tee >(perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g'>>"$LogFile".plain) $LogFile -a >/dev/null
```

Notes:

- Used `>>` instead of `>`, as expected for an incremental log file.
- Used `-a` for the `tee` command for the same reason above.
- I would prefer to use `sed` instead of `perl`, but all the `sed` examples I have found until now do not work. If someone knows, please report.